QGIS - split raster file into categories (WorldCover) for proximity (Raster Distance)
I have a large raster file from WorldCover (https://esa-worldcover.org/en) with landcover categorisation. My goal is to generate distance rasters, i.e. nearest distance to a given feature (with the "Proximity (Raster Distance)" tool) for each land cover category within this raster file.
When I open the raster(s) in QGIS, I get all the categories together, that is, it doesn't look like I can e.g. save them separately. Here's an example:

So this doesn't allow me to save each category of interest separately. In any case, I tried using the proximity tool and select there which category I want to get (e.g. number 10), and it doesn't seem that I can select it there either:

Any ideas on how to overcome this? Or any other solution to obtain the distance rasters per category.
